# JSF component doesn't update if changes came from grid click

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces

I have a JSF/IceFaces application where there is a screen divided into 3 sections. Search fields, a grid and some details fields below. Currently if I enter some data into the search fields and click on a Search button (!) the grid shows the results and a certain method is called that puts the first result record's details into the backing beans of the details fields below the grid. This shows that there is no problem with the way I put data into the details fields.

However I have a gridclicklistener method as well that would like to change the detail fields according to the selection. After the click the same method gets called with the correct parameters that works well if invoked after the click on the Search button. The data is updated in the backing beans but the changes are not rendered even if I click the refresh button in the browser.

I found that if I click on the search button, the data-updating-method gets called from `InvokeApplicationPhase.execute`. When I get to this line after the grid click then it is from the `ApplyRequestValuesPhase`.

Do you have any ideas what could make this difference and how to get this work?

**Update:**

I can clearly see the updated value in the backing bean but it is not reflected on screen at all, even after F5.

Comment: I dont understand much from this post, but you have to make sure/debug that your model is updated.

Comment: the model is updated for sure, I checked that with debugging

Comment: Apparently 2 HTTP requests are being sent. Verify this with a HTTP tracker like Firebug/Chrome.

Comment: Checked with Firebug but after clicking on the grid, only one HTTP request is sent.

Comment: One HTTP request is sent when I click on the Search button and the field value updates nicely. One HTTP request is sent when I click on the grid and the field value does not update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is causing your original problem.

With the icefaces push renderer however you could force an update:

http://wiki.icefaces.org/display/ICE/Getting+Started+with+ICEfaces+2#GettingStartedwithICEfaces2-icepush

Comment: Is there any difference between this method and pressing F5 in the browser? If the field value does not update the latter way, how would the first help me..?

Comment: If doing a page refresh in the browser doesn't work then initiating rerendering through the push mechanism probably won't work as well.